# Woocommerce Show Single Product on Homepage

Tags: php, templates, plugins

I am currently learning PHP & how to customize Wordpress.

I have a shop that I set up on Wordpress using the Woocommerce plugin.  The shop holds only a single item.  Since I only have 1 item to sell, I would like to show the product on my homepage in such a fashion where the complete product page is shown on the homepage.

Here is some code i've been trying to get to work (this is placed in the home.php file):

```
$prodpage = array(
'post_type' => 'product',
'posts_per_page' => 1,
'taxonomy' => 'banner',
'term' => 'banner'
);
$featured_query = new WP_Query( $prodpage );

if ($featured_query->have_posts()) :   

    while ($featured_query->have_posts()) :   

        $featured_query->the_post();  

        $product = get_product( $featured_query->product->ID );  

    // Product Info Output Here

endwhile;  

endif;  

wp_reset_query(); // Query Reset
```

I have also tried using query_posts in this manner:

```
if ( is_home() ) {
query_posts( 'p=31' );
}
```

The good news is that I don't get flagged for any syntax errors.  The bad news is that I am afraid my logic is off somewhere as I get a page with only the WP header and footer.  The mid section where the product should show up is not showing up.

I really appreciate any guidance you guys are able to give! :)

Comment: Replace the curly quotes in `‘banner’` and other occurrences with simple quotes `'`.

Comment: Thank you for catching that!!  I took out the curly quotes as directed. Unfortunately, that didn't enable the information to show up. :(

Comment: Next step: Read [this thread](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/50761/when-to-use-wp-query-query-posts-and-pre-get-posts).

Comment: `'term'` doesn't exist as parameter for `WP_Query`, it should be `'terms'`. Besides that, it should be part of a `'tax_query'`; the `'taxonomy'` parameter too. But because you only have and want one product there is no sense in that, you don't need it.

Comment: Thank you both!  I am reading up on queries now.  Great information in the article you posted, toscho!  I was going back and forth between the Wordpress Codex and PHP manual but wasn't 100% solid in my understanding.  The link you posted helped fill in the gap!  Thank you!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Why not just use the [product_page](http://docs.woothemes.com/document/woocommerce-shortcodes/#section-7) shortcode?

In the page content:

```
[product_page id="31"]
```

In code in the home page template:

```
<?php echo do_shortcode('[product_page id="31"]'); ?>
```

Comment: Wow!  Thank you!  I came across that method in my search but felt (read assumed) that it would only pull up the thumbnail and add-to-cart button.  Yeah... assumptions.  Sheesh.  Again, Thank you! :)

Comment: the `[product]` shortcode does that :)

Comment: I tried that but it only showed the thumbnail and an add-to-cart button.  The code snippet you provided for the manual shortcode actually showed the complete product page.  I wonder if all I needed to do was put [product_page id="31"] in my Wordpress post.  Would the complete page have showed up then?  Off to test!